# Go program creating OS threads for every goroutine even though there are no syscalls

Tags: go, goroutine

I am using go 1.3.3.
I am running the following go program on my mac which is 10.9.2 Intel Core i7:

```
package main
import (
         "fmt"
         "sync"
)

func justprint(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
     for j := 0; j < 1000000; j++ {
          fmt.Printf("Printing %d\n", i)
     }
     wg.Done()
}

func main() {
     var wg sync.WaitGroup
     for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
          wg.Add(1)
          go justprint(i, &wg)
     }
     wg.Wait()
     fmt.Println("Done!!")
}
```

In the activity monitor i see 8 threads being spawned if i run this program. In the goroutine justprint() there are no syscalls, so I was expecting no extra threads created when i run this program other than the default threads which any go program creates. But as i increase the number of go routine calls, the OS threads are also increasing accordingly. Could anyone please help me understand why this is happening?

Comment: @CharlieTumahai Nah, print to stdout uses the special `out` and `outs` instructions of course!

Comment: You are right...i didnt realize. Thanks a lot for clearing that up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's creating one thread per goroutine? Try increasing the number of goroutines to 1000. I'll bet the number of threads stays about constant. Go creates and manages several threads to handle async I/O.